# Knockout.js not finding function in data binding

Tags: knockout.js, magento2

I have a Magento2 template with a button :

```
 <button data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'update-cart-item-'+item_id,
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           click: incrementClickCounter,
                           title: $t('Update')
                           }"
                            class="update-cart-item"
                            style="display: none">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Update'"></span>
                    </button>
```

The part i have added here is

> click: incrementClickCounter

In the script tag above the html page i have

```
<script>
        require(["jquery","ko"], function ($) {
                        var viewModel = {
                    numberOfClicks : ko.observable(0),
                    incrementClickCounter : function() {
                        var previousCount = this.numberOfClicks();
                        this.numberOfClicks(previousCount + 1);
                        console.log(this.numberOfClicks);
                    }
                };
        });
    </script>
```

but i am getting the error

> Message: incrementClickCounter is not defined

Comment: It seems you didn't provide the whole relevant code, so let me ask: what's the relation between your `viewModel` and cart items? I presume you've got an array of cart items somewhere, but where is it defined? is it inside `viewModel`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm acctually able to inject the jquery into the binding like this :

```
<button afterRender="function (target, viewModel) {
                        console.log('Rendered element:', target);
                        console.log('Associated view model:', viewModel);
                        console.log(this === viewModel);
                                jQuery(target).click(function() {
                                    alert( 'Handler for .click() called.');
                                  });
                    }"
```

But it feels very dirty

Comment: indeed, you shouldn't do that. can you answer my comment above? help me help you.

Comment: Im struggling to fid the .js file that the update-cart-item buttons KO functions are in, ive added a test function to almost every .js file in vendor

Comment: not sure how does this answers my comment, so let me ask again: what's the relationship between your `viewModel` and cart items? I presume you've got an array of cart items somewhere. Where is it defined? is it inside `viewModel`? somewhere else?

Comment: It's magento2 the items come from there

Comment: And what's the relationship between your `viewModel` and a cart item? that's what you need to figure out. e.g., is `viewModel` the parent of a cart item? the grandparent? something else? then, according to this relationship, you'd know how to use `incrementClickCounter`, e.g. call it upon `$root`, `$parent`, or something else.

Comment: @HeyJude This iw what i'm struggling to underdstand. It is the magento2 minicart i cannot find the .js file it is bound too ive added a test fucntion in every single js file

Comment: @HeyJude ive overridden web/js/view/minicart.js and the override is working, all the functions are in there like closeminicart etc but when i add loadJsAfterKoRender function and add <input data-bind="loadJsAfterKoRender : test,attr: {... its saing function loadJsAfterKoRender not found

Comment: maybe this answer can help you: [How to use Knockout JS within Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/103889)